# Working on a scenario where two entity types have two kinds of relationship, one of which is ISA-to-ISA

Tags: database-design, erd

I am a student of a university, and my teacher thinks my entity-relationship diagram (ERD) is weird. The ERD is about a ramen restaurant.

The order receipt looks like this:

1. Tofu Ramen         $3
   Topping:

   - Meatball        $1
   - Kerupuk         $1
2. Tofu Ramen         $3
   Topping: none

You can see, there is *detail* that has *detail*, in other word, orderitem has topping.

**Let me show the ERD:**

*ISA is the generalization.
* *minuman*=drink

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

**This is the output schema:**

[image: Output scheme]

**The question:**

The relation *added* is the problem. Is it correct or I am wrong? Please correct me if it wrong.

Pardon my English.